# ElasticSearch: map required (non-dynamic) fields but have one property ("meta data") dynamic

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I want to create an index that holds some content that represents articles.

An article consist of a `title`, `excerpt`, `body`, `publish_date` and `meta`. All of these are required, except Meta. I want no other properties to be settable.

Additionally I want "`meta`" to be able to hold whatever data is put in there.

I attempted with setting the dynamic parameter on the article to false and then the meta object to true, but with no luck. (Example can be seen below)

(Note: I understand that using a meta as such mean that all the values of the array will be of the same data type and I am okay with this.)

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "article": {
            "type":"object",
            "dynamic" : "false",
            "properties": {
                "title":          {"type": "string"},
                "excerpt":        {"type": "string"},
                "body":           {"type": "string"},
                "publish_date":   {"type": "date"},
                "meta": {
                    "type":       "object"
                    "dynamic" :   "true",
                    "properties": {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***TL:DR - How do I define a mapping that makes certain properties required, but leaves one property (meta array/object) open for filling, while preventing any property that isn't required to be set outside of the meta object.***

Comment: Good question. Did you manage to solve that TL;DR challenge?

Comment: @mgaert Yes, the problem was solved in the answer I gave below. Setting the object, in this case Article, to dynamic strict, and then defining a new property "meta" with dynamic set to true.

Comment: Does this make title, excerpt and body required or does it just prevent indexing of documents that have unexpected fields?

Comment: It makes title, excerpt, and body required and allows you to put unexpected fields in meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a simple mistake preventing the functionality to properly trigger.

Using the JSON below, setting the dynamic property to strict on the initial article mapping and the "meta-stash" dynamic property to true, actually did give the desired functionality.

Turned out the usage of `false`, rather than `strict`, also disabled exceptions from being thrown, causing the initial confusion.

So, as also stated in the documentation,

- `true`: Add new fields dynamically—the default
- `false`: Ignore new fields
- `strict`: Throw an exception if an unknown field is encountered

***Correct mapping:***

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "article": {
            "type":"object",
            "dynamic" : "strict",
            "properties": {
                "title":          {"type": "string"},
                "excerpt":        {"type": "string"},
                "body":           {"type": "string"},
                "publish_date":   {"type": "date"},
                "meta": {
                    "type":       "object"
                    "dynamic" :   "true",
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```